# C++/CLI from MFC extension DLL

Tags: mfc, c++-cli

I have an MFC application that uses several MFC extension DLL's. I want this app (and several other similar apps) to be able to access some parts of the .net framework. I wrote a C# library to do the .net work I want and was hoping to be able to write an MFC dll to hide all the C++/CLI code from my apps. The apps would stay as pure MFC apps and the only C++/CLI code would be in my new MFX extension DLL. However when I did this the apps crashed when accessing the new MFC C++/CLI dll. If I put the C++/CLI code in the apps it works ok and I can debug my way all the way in to the C#.

Does anyone understand why the dll idea doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you gave some detail of the crash - an address, exception type etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference managed assemblies from pure native code. You have to either flip the /clr switch on the consumer (either project-wide or in certain files,) or do some interop.

One interop option that will allow your consumer to say pure native is calling into the managed assembly via [COM Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have run into a similar problem. My setup was similar - A pure MFC app with a pure MFC DLL which in turn interacted with the C++/CLI DLL. Everything would run fine, but it would crash on exit. The problem was exacerbated while testing the pure MFC DLL using CppUnit.

On debugging, I found out that due to a bug, my C++ code was throwing first-chance exceptions for access violations (objects referenced via a dangling pointer) on exit. Now, the C++ runtime ignores these violations on exit, whereas the CLR does not. The CLR runtime throws an unhandled exception making it appear that the program / unit-test crashed.

Your problem maybe different, but it does sound quite similar to the one I had.

Answer (score 0):

The MFC dll project references the C# library and has one file compiled with /clr that handles the interface into my C# library. I have actually seen this work sometimes at run time but have never been able to debug into the MFC dll or into the C# code. However it doesn't seem to be at all stable and crashes in the majority of cases.